# Filtering between two dates in excel vba

Tags: vba, excel, filtering

I need help to filter between two dates and it's giving me an error:

> Named argument not found

**my code**

```
Dim StartDate As String
Dim EndDate As String
'
StartDate = Date
EndDate = Date + 365
'
ActiveSheet.AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:=">=StartDate", Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=EndDate"
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Figured out the error, but now is filtering out all of the data due to today's date not being in the range of data. Any thoughts on correcting this error?

Comment: please update your post with code without the error you found and more details about data to be filtered (what cells are they in, and the likes)

Comment: Please see below:

Comment: Dim StartDate As String
Dim EndDate As String
StartDate = Date
EndDate = Date + 365
ActiveSheet.Range("A1:AO1").AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:="<=StartDate", Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=EndDate"

Comment: cells could be anywhere from G2 to G10000000, but they will always be in column G

Comment: @PrivateResearch Your code is not easily readable in a comment.  Please edit your question to update it.

Comment: @PrivateResearch Oh, and `StartDate` and `EndDate` should be declared as dates and not strings.

Answer (score 4):

if your dates are actual `Date` values (i.e. not `String` ones looking like dates), then go like this:

```
Dim StartDate As Date
Dim EndDate As Date
StartDate = Date
EndDate = Date + 365
ActiveSheet.Range("A1:AO1").AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:=">=" & CDbl(StartDate), Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=" & CDbl(EndDate)
```

Comment: it still filters out all dates.

Comment: based on your feedback though, I took a look at the formatting and it shows as "10/21/2016  12:12:26 PM". could this have something to do with the issue?

Comment: **my code**Dim StartDate As String Dim EndDate As String StartDate = Date EndDate = Date + 365 ActiveSheet.Range("A1:AO1").AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:="<=StartDate", Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=EndDate

Comment: Dim StartDate As String
Dim EndDate As String
'
StartDate = Date
EndDate = Date + 365
'
ActiveSheet.AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:=">=StartDate", Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=EndDate"

Comment: You're messing things up. Update your code with the _exact_ code from my answer and report what happens. Also you may select a cell in column "G" with a "date" and 1) say what you see in the formula bar 2)  type in Immediate Window `?selection.numberformat` , press "return" and report what's the returned value

Answer (score 0):

I posted a sample file on my google drive.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2w6b7-P-pX1R0dlTlFUSl9xZlE

I can describe the logic, but it's just easier for you to download it, play around with it, and see the mechanics of it.

Answer (score 0):

Basic logic was the issue... mix up of the start and end date logic (should be EndDate = Date and StartDate = Date - 365).

Sorry for the troubles!