# VBA, filtering by date, how to stop excel converting date to number?

Tags: excel, vba

I am using the following code, however whenever I check the filter, the date is on the numeric value of the date, and not "20/01/2020", Thanks.

```
filter_date = "20/01/2020"
filter_date = Format(filter_date, "dd/mm/yyyy")

ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$L$10").AutoFilter Field:=8, _
Criteria1:=">=" & Format(filter_date, "dd/mm/yyyy"), Operator:=xlAnd
```

Comment: How did you declare your `filter_date` variable?  And just to be sure: the dates in your table are text strings, and not real dates?

Comment: It's declared as a string

Comment: I'd strongly encourage you to convert it to [double](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40820757/filtering-between-two-dates-in-excel-vba) and filter like that, you may get random errors while using the logic that you're following.

Comment: Seconding the comment by @Sgdva, also take a look at my answer to [auto filter with column formatted as a date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19767043/autofilter-with-column-formatted-as-date)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Alternate Answer

The comments under the question have a solution, but I would suggest keeping the `Date` datatype and go with something like this, which should work:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

Dim filter_date As Date  ' Declaring the var type as Date

filter_date = #20/1/2020#  ' Use the # sign around a date to identify it as Date

ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$L$10").AutoFilter Field:=8, _
Criteria1:=">=" & filter_date, Operator:=xlAnd

End Sub
```

I think this is easier and shorter, plus you can more easily read your date in code.  Using the `#` around the date is the way to assign dates.

Comment: Thanks, adding an ' seems to also work, Criteria1:=">='" & filter_date also works